What control the RPM of an engine?
can you tell me what controls the rpm of an engine? Is it more fuel, more rpm (if so plz explain this to me) or is it controlled by a computer?

When? At idling? When a gear is engaged, the rpm is a factor of the road speed and the gearing. It's not 'controlled'. With an auto box there are more factors involved, such as slipping drive bands or clutches.

@WeatherVane let say a stationary engine and just the engine.

In modern engines it is controlled by a computer, the engine management system. I see you tagged both diesel and gasoline.

What are you driving? Older cars with carburetors and distributors control engine rpm from the gas pedal opening/ closing a throttle plate controlling air flow into the engine. Fuel is mixed with air from the venturi effect of sucking fuel thru a fuel nozzle. Modern cars using EFI systems control engine rpm indirectly from the electronic pedal telling the engine computer throttle position and determining how much fuel to inject into each cylinder. This is the drive-by-wire system. The computer controls fuel mixtures and spark. The driver simply pushes or releases the gas pedal for control.

@FDryer clear crystal, i think this is for gasoline. For diesel i know they use injectors without spark blug but they conponsate that with high pressure but not exactly how for old and modern engine can you explain plz thank you.

@WeatherVane yes i need to know for both.

I think your best option is to read a book about engines.

@WeatherVane between a book and an experienced person i will choose an experienced person there is somethings that you cant found or learn from a book and knowing my self i am a digger for example as mentionned @F Dryer in old cars about carburator he give me a deriction and what i founded cant be in a book watch this from 14:37 did you know that?

But this will turn into a stream of conversation questions. Read a book, or if you prefer, watch more videos.

The venturi effect, creating a vacuum to pull fuel into the airflow; basic operation of carburetors. The video is a wonderful way of describing a complex operation. As mentioned, reading material and/or engineering/science videos can help, but you'll have to search carefully for good presentations. Electronic fuel injection for gasoline engines is virtually standard everywhere. Find info on; basic 4-stroke fundamentals, then EFI systems - replacing carburetors with injectors@higher fuel pressures, sensors feeding signals to the engine control computer to control everything.

@FDryer i know the basic of 4 stroke fundamental we studied that at high school i know about the injection types, i know about some sensors like in catalytic and in common rail. I was talking to someone about increasing the torque of a diesel  engine and i know to achieve that it is necessary to increase the pressure by feeding more air if not pure oxygen and then he told me that this will increase the rpm so here i am asking.

Perhaps you didn't specify type of engine, fuel, carburetor, EFI, 2-stroke, 4-stroke, diesel, turbo or super charging.

@FDryer  what make think that?

after help of members of this community and a lot of search i found that the engine RPM is controlled by how much fuel is injected into the cylinder, in combination with air intake.
To be more specific the injection duration (how long the injector stays open affects the amount of fuel that will be injected).
injector duration is what controls engine rpm

That answer is very limited and is incorrect in many situations. What about those injectors that can inject fuel at different pressures?

@RoryAlsop you just aproved that my answer is correct with your comment thank you to you.

Hi @Tintin - no, I didn't. Sorry you misunderstood. Duration is just one factor.

Hello @RoryAlsop "at different pressures" means different amount of fuel so it is correct. Listen Rory there is difference between control and influencer(situation) like load envirenment(altutude....) ‍♂️

Your answer only focuses on injector duration, but is missing: injector pressure, lag or lead timings, spark plug timings, valve timings and a whole host of other things, which is why I have downvoted the answer - until you fix it, it is an incorrect answer.
